# how to print data inside a char pointer (c++)?

Tags: c++

I have a

```
function(const char * data)
{
//how to print the data which is inside the data
}
```

when I debug I see only the address. If I print (*data) nothing is printed.

Any idea?

Comment: `print` is not a standard C++ feature, and if it is a function in your debugger, then you should specify which debugger you're using.  `*data` refers only to the first character at the address `data`: if that character is a control character it may not appear to be printed - it depends on your terminal/console software.  Note that an empty string in ASCIIZ representation is simply a 0 value (not a '0' character), and probably won't print usefully.  You might try print(data), but you're not specifying enough about your environment to give you a confident answer.

Comment: I wonder if he's talking about gdb ?

Comment: Please specify the debugger you are using. From the `print` command you are using my best guess is that you are using gdb. If so, try the `x` command. It allows you to print contents of a block of memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

void function(const char * data)
{
    std::cout << data;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`printf("%s\n", data)` works for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
std::cout << std::string(data);
```

Comment: How's that different from std::cout << data?

Comment: because data is an int ! ! !: being a pointer means being an integer. So if you ask to print a int, it prints an int.

Comment: No. A pointer is a pointer, despite being represented as plain integer internally (in most cases). `cout << data` will **not** print the address it points to but output the nul-terminated string it points to. `char *` is not `int` (or any integral type at all) and therefore invokes a different overload of `operator<<` - one that knows how to output c strings.

Comment: but that doesnt make my answer ANY wrong. std::string is the C++ way of manipulating strings.

Comment: @Stephane: Except that you can print a zero-terminated string referred to by a pointer to its first character directly, without the overhead of creating a (probably dynamically allocated) string from it.

Comment: @sbi... yep of course... I didn't know about the operator << overloaded for const char *.

Comment: @Stephane: your code would work, but it wastes CPU cycles unnecessarily by  allocating memory and copying the string.

Comment: probably, but latest time visual studio print my const char * as an int, made me convert them all as std::string. I don't say this is good.